# Reducing boilerplate for base to derived delegation in non-virtual polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, polymorphism

Consider a closed<sup>1</sup> class hierarchy such as the following:

```
class B {...}; 
class D1 final : public B {...};
class D2 final : public B {...};
```

Where `B` is a abstract<sup>2</sup> base class and `D1` and `D2` are its derived classes.

Due to implementation constraints or design, none of these classes have any `virtual` methods but member functions on `B` that have different implementations in `D1` and `D2` are simply delegated to the actual most-derived type by making a runtime check of the derived type, as follows:

```
class B {
  bool isD1;
protected:
  B(bool isD1) : isD1{isD1} {}
public:
  std::string to_string() {
    return isD1 ? static_cast<D1*>(this)->to_string() : static_cast<D2*>(this)->to_string();
  }
}

class D1 final : public B {
public:
  D1() : B(true) {}
  std::string to_string() { // D1 specific implementation ... }
}

class D2 final : public B {
public:
  D2() : B(false) {}
  std::string to_string() { // D2 specific implementation ... }
}
```

Here the `to_string` method on `B` simply checks if the most-derived type of `B` is `D1` or `D2` and calls the appropriate method (also called `to_string` in both cases).

Cool.

Now imagine there are 10 more methods like `B::to_string`. What can I do in C++11 to reduce the delegation boilerplate in `B`, without resorting to macros?

In C++14 it seems a reasonable approach would be a generic delegation mechanism, like:

```
class B {
  ...

  template <typename F>
  auto delegate(F&& f) -> decltype(f(D1{})) {
    return isD1 : f(*static_cast<D1*>(this)) : f(*static_cast<D2*>(this));
  }

  std::string to_string() {
    return delegate([](auto&& b){ return b.to_string(); });
  }
}
```

Here the `[](auto&& b){ return b.to_string(); }` generic lambda works whether ultimately passed a `D1` or `D2` (since both have `to_string` methods). In C++11 I don't see an equivalently concise way to express this.

Any ideas?

Of course, you could use macros to duplicate a non-generic macro and pass it to a 2-argument `delegate` method (that takes separate functors for `D1` and `D2`) but I'd like to avoid macros.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here *closed* means that the set of derived classes of `B` is fixed and known at runtime.

<sup>2</sup> Abstract *in concept* but not in the "pure `virtual`" sense. That is this class should not be directly instantiated - the only entire objects that make sense are its derived classes. The various constructors are made `protected` to enforce this.

Comment: Am I correct you'd reject a solution based in pre-processor macros?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - correct. In fact I'm already using such a solution since it is easy to write a `DELEGATE(x)` macro such that `DELEGATE(std::string, to_string)` simply expands to the `B::to_string()` implementation shown above, and then a couple other macros to handle functions with arguments, etc.

Comment: @BeeOnRope - I've completely misunderstood the question; sorry.

Comment: Is the intent to make the code pretty or to reduce maintenance?  I.e., would rendering `class B` from a template (or other code-generation) be in-scope?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - both - DRY helps both with maintenance and (often) makes it clear. Using code generation is out of scope here I think because I'm not already doing that and it's a big jump in build and comprehension complexity (i.e., there are good reasons to generate code, but this is probably way too minor to qualify).

Comment: Can you not apply CRTP here (since it would solve the issue as presented)? Wanted to mention it, just in case, but you may have circumstances where it is not possible.

Comment: @Shaggi - the problem CRTP (here I'm assuming something like making `B` a template class and then `class D1 : public B<D1> {}` and so on) is that then `D1` and `D2` no longer have a common base class since `B<D1>` and `B<D2>` are two entirely different classes without an inheritance relationship. So any method taking a `B&`, for example, won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
  template <typename F1, typename F2>
  auto delegate(F1 f1, F2 f2) -> decltype((D1{}.*f1)()) {
    return isD1 ? (static_cast<D1*>(this)->*f1)() : (static_cast<D2*>(this)->*f2)();
  }

  std::string to_string() {
    return delegate(&D1::to_string, &D2::to_string);
  }
```

You could also make it more strongly typed:

```
  template <typename Result>
  Result delegate(Result (D1::*f1)(), Result (D2::*f2)()) {
    return isD1 ? (static_cast<D1*>(this)->*f1)() : (static_cast<D2*>(this)->*f2)();
  }
```

Comment: Looks good. `delegate` could also be extended to perfectly forward additional arguments to the derived functions, assuming some of them might have parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it's an abomination. But I thought I'd share because

- the OP implied he/she was using a much simpler macro-based scheme, and
- it approaches a "zero boilerplate soluton".

The following is a working example.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <delegate_macros>

#define FOREACH_DELEGATE(A) \
  A(std::string, to_string, (),      ())\
  A(void,        setInt,    (int a), (a))\

class B
{
  DECLARE_VTAB_MEMBERS
public:
  B(DELEGATE_ARGS) : INITIALIZER_LIST { }

  DEFINE_DELEGATORS
};

class D1 : public B
{
  int m_i;
public:
  D1() : B(PASS_DELEGATES) {}
  void setInt(int i) {m_i = i;}
  std::string to_string() {std::stringstream ss; ss << "D1:" << m_i; return ss.str();}
};

class D2 : public B
{
  int m_i;
public:
  D2() : B(PASS_DELEGATES) {}
  void setInt(int i) {m_i = i * 5;}
  std::string to_string() {std::stringstream ss; ss << "D2:" << m_i; return ss.str();}
};
```

Where

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;

  B *ref = &d1;

  ref->setInt(2);
  std::cout << "((B*)&d1)->toString: " << ref->to_string() << std::endl;

  ref = &d2;
  ref->setInt(2);
  std::cout << "((B*)&d2)->toString: " << ref->to_string() << std::endl;
}
```

Yields

```
$ ./a.out
((B*)&d1)->toString: D1:2
((B*)&d2)->toString: D2:10
```

The macros in `delegate_macros` are independent of the structure of `B` and its subclasses:

```
#define MAKE_DELEGATOR(ret, name, params, args)\
  ret name params\
  {\
    return (this ->* m_##name) args;\
  }

#define MAKE_DELEGATE_REF(ret, name, params, args) (ret (B::*) params)&name,

#define DECLARE_VTAB_MEMBER(t,n,p,a) t (B::*m_##n)p;

#define MAKE_CTOR_INITIALIZER(t,n,p,a) m_##n(n),
#define MAKE_CTOR_ARG(t,n,p,a) t (B::*n) p,
#define MAKE_CTOR_PARAMS(t,n,p,a) t (B::*m_##n)p,

#define DECLARE_VTAB_MEMBERS FOREACH_DELEGATE(DECLARE_VTAB_MEMBER) char dummy;
#define INITIALIZER_LIST     FOREACH_DELEGATE(MAKE_CTOR_INITIALIZER) dummy()
#define DEFINE_DELEGATORS    FOREACH_DELEGATE(MAKE_DELEGATOR)
#define DELEGATE_ARGS        FOREACH_DELEGATE(MAKE_CTOR_ARG) void *
#define PASS_DELEGATES       FOREACH_DELEGATE(MAKE_DELEGATE_REF) NULL
```

There are a few reasons I call this an abomination:

- It manually makes a VTABLE...and if you want a VTABLE, just use virtual.
- It converts simple typos into pages of output.
- It performs an unchecked cast of each subclass' pointer-to-method to the `(B::*)` variant.

  - And calls the subclass method using the pointer-to-method so-cast.
- It adds dummy constructor arguments and member vars to make macro expansion easier.
- No-one can read it unless they've spent years writing this kind of macro.
- FOREACH_DELEGATE has to be defined in each translation unit where you want to use the macros, so it's really only appropriate if `B` and all its subclasses are defined in one file.  You'd have to make additional macros to separate declaring the delegators vs. defining them if you want to put B in a header alongside FOREACH_DELEGATE.